# I was making an app and while i was running the code, this showed up: `main.lua`: 290: attempt to index field(a nil value)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I was making an app and while i was running the code, this showed up:
`main.lua`: 290: attempt to index field(a nil value)

```
function check()
print('check game over')
    for i = 1, Balls.numChildren do
print(i)
        if (Balls[i].y > display.contentHeight) then -- LINE 290
            display.remove(Balls[i])
            Balls[i] = nil

            if (tonumber(ballRemain.text) <= 0) then
                alert('lose')               
            end
        end
    end 
end
```

I checked a couple of times and still couldn't find what's going on. Someone told me that it could be because I didn't remove an event listener, but I'm not sure. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you point, what line is 'line 290'?

Comment: Obviously, line 290 is the one that contains `Balls[i].y`

Comment: Obviously you tried to index a field and it was `nil`

Comment: Something to do with how numChildren is computed? Can you show output you get if you `print("ball", i)` just before the `if Balls[i]`?

Answer (score 0):

`check` looks like a function that is called multiple times. It can set `Balls[i]` to `nil` for arbitrary values of `i`. Presumably `Balls` has a number of slots that may or may not contain an object. So, change line 290 to check if the slot is occupied before attempting to do anything with the object:

```
if (Balls[i] and Balls[i].y > display.contentHeight) then -- LINE 290
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i tried print statement and looked at the corona simulator output this is what i got:

Check game over

1

2

Check game over

1

2

and this goes on until it reaches Runtime error and `main.lua`: 290: attempt to index field(a nil value)